# pass partial list of arguments from the parent script to the child script

Tags: bash

Suppose my parent script is called with `n` arguments, and I want to pass all arguments from argument #3 to the child script.

How do I do that in bash script?

I know `$@` would get you the entire argument list, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `shift` to remove the first two arguments:

```
shift 2
child_script "$@"
```

If you need to use `$1` and `$2`, you can save them in variables first.

Another option is to assign the arguments to an array:

```
args=("$@")
```

remove the first two elements of the array:

```
unset args[0]
unset args[1]
```

Then call the child script with this array:

```
child_script "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: But what if I want to use `$1` and `$2` later in the file? SHould I just save their values in a separate variable?

Comment: That's what I would probably do, but I added another solution to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
child_script "${@:3}"
```

If you wanted to pass four arguments starting at argument 3:

```
child_script "${@:3:4}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the discussion of keeping the original values:
You could do the shift in the child script.